# Javascript, uncaught reference error: function() not defined

Tags: javascript, api, rest, twitter, photobucket

Well, I can't seem to figure out why my function is not defined on click, or onload.

I've ran it through firebug, and can't see any syntax errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/170a71mj/1/

The code in question:

```
    function getAlbums(user, album) {
        var url = "http://api.photobucket.com/album/";

        url = url + encodeURIComponent( user + "/" + album )
        var json = callPhotobucket( url, "format=json" );

    }

    function getTag(media) {
    var url = "http://api.photobucket.com/media/";

    url = url + encodeURIComponent(media) + "/tag" ;
    var json = callPhotobucket(url, "format=json");
    }

    function getTimestamp() {
        var timestamp = new Date().valueOf();
        timestamp = timestamp / 1000;
        timestamp = Math.ceil( timestamp );
        return timestamp;
    }

    function ping() {
    auth_url = callPhotobucket( "http://api.photobucket.com/ping", "format=json" );
    }

    function callPhotobucket( url, format ) {
        try {
            if( url == undefined ) {
            url = "http://api.photobucket.com/ping";
            }

            if( format == undefined ) {
                format = "format=json";
            }

        var timestamp = getTimestamp();
        auth_nonce="nonce" + timestamp;

        auth_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
        auth_timestamp = "" + timestamp;

        auth_version="1.0";

        auth_consumer = "&oauth_consumer_key="+ encodeURIComponent( consumer_key );
        nonce = "&oauth_nonce="+ encodeURIComponent( auth_nonce );
        auth_sig_method = "&oauth_signature_method="+ encodeURIComponent( auth_method );
        auth_timestamp = "&oauth_timestamp="+ encodeURIComponent( auth_timestamp );
        version = "&oauth_version=" + encodeURIComponent( auth_version );

        paramstring = format + auth_consumer + nonce + auth_sig_method + auth_timestamp + version;

        method = "GET";

        base = encodeURIComponent( method ) + "&" + encodeURIComponent( url ) + "&" + encodeURIComponent( paramstring );

        sig_hash = getSignature( consumer_secret+"&", base );
        auth_sign = "&oauth_signature=" + sig_hash;

        auth_url = url + "?" + paramstring + "&" + auth_sign;
        myalert( ""+ auth_url+"");
        return auth_url;

        }

        catch (err) {
        alert( "Error " + err );
        }
    }

    function getSignature(key, baseString) {
        b64pad = '=';
        var signature = b64_hmac_sha1(key, baseString);
        return signature;
    }
```

Comment: change fiddle to nowrap in head. also include your javascript in html file.

Comment: Cyan, thank you for the response. I am including the javascript in the html file, in <script> </script tags. I have also updated the original post with nowrap in head.

Comment: I've also added fake consumer_key and consumer_secret in the fiddle. the sha error is because i have not included it in the fiddle. I am still getting ping and getAlbum not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the sha1 implementation I included. After much testing (line by line), when removing the include it worked.

Thanks